# Is there a PartDelete like there is a TakeDrop

Tags: list-manipulation, built-in-symbols

`TakeDrop` is nice because after taking a subarray, it also returns the remaining subarray.  But it is limited in that the part specification can only be ranges, and not specific elements.

For example, `TakeDrop[{a, b, c, d}, {1, 3}]` yields `{{a, b, c}, {d}}`, but it is not possible to do something like `TakeDrop[{a, b, c, d}, {{1}, {3}}]` to get `{{a, c}, {b, d}}`.

The obvious needed generalization would be named something like `PartDelete`, but I cannot find it.  Is there such a function?

Comment: Like `Through[{Extract, Delete}[{a, b, c, d}, {{1}, {3}}]]`? I don't think there's a built-in, but as you can see it's not too hard to do. (FWIW, I still do `Through[{Take, Drop}[(* stuff *)]]` out of habit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As J.M. mentioned in the comments, `Through[{Extract, Delete}]` does the job:

```
Through[{Extract, Delete}[{a, b, c, d}, {{1}, {3}}]]
```